# Difficulty creating random words under conditions

Tags: python, for-loop

I need k words to be generated, until the sum of all the characters that make up the list is equal to or greater than 25

```
    import random
    for x in range(k): 
        n=("a","b","c","d")
        cc=[''.join(random.choice(n) for _ in range(random.choice(range(2,5))))]
        print(cc)

    def sumt(input1):

        l = list(input1)
        total = sum(len(i) for i in l)
        return int(total)

    print(sumt([cc]))
```

Comment: So, what is your question here?

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I need k words to be generated, until the sum of all the characters that make up the list is equal to or greater than 25" Okay, so what happens when you run the code? How is that different from what you want? What is your understanding of the problem in the code, and specifically what do you need to know in order to solve the problem? Please read [ask] and then **ask a question**. Also, please read [mre]. It is not possible to test this code, because there is no definition for `k`.

Comment: (Hint: the goal is to repeat the process *until* some condition is met, yes? Which seems more appropriate: a `for` loop, or a `while` loop?)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `for` loop if you have a variable amount of iteration to do

Have a method that generate a word, then call until you reach the good total length

```
chars = "abcd"

def new_word():
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(random.choice(range(2, 5))))

def generate(total_length):
    result = []
    result_length = 0
    while result_length < total_length:
        result.append(new_word())
        result_length += len(result[-1])  # sum with len of last word
    return result

x = generate(25)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, you want to build a list of words until the sum of all characters is >= 25? I prefer using classes...

```
import random

class WordList:
  def __init__(self):
    self.choices = ['a','b','c','d']
    self.threshold = 25
    self.char_sum = 0
    self.lst = []   

    self.build_list()
    
  def build_list(self):
    '''Build a list of words until sum of all chars
    meets or exceeds the threshold.
    '''
    while self.char_sum < self.threshold:
      self.generate_word()
      self.char_sum = sum(len(i) for i in self.lst)

  def generate_word(self):
    '''Generate a single word with 2 to 5 characters.
    '''
    _word = ''.join(random.choice(self.choices) for _ in range(random.choice(range(2,5))))
    self.lst.append(_word)
```

Usage:

```
new_list = WordList().lst
print(new_list)
```